# How to pick values from array one by one jmeter

Tags: jmeter

EX.hitList values=233,234 Stored in Id_1=233 and id_2=234.I want use this two values one after one.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller), Set Input variable prefix = Id and Output variable = currentId

and then inside ForEach Controller you will able to use the variable: `${currentId}` in 2 iterations

Comment: Tried but not luck